# The Sensor data from the nodemcu is not updating to blynk

Tags: esp8266, arduino-esp8266, nodemcu, blynk

I have managed to get the first initial values updated to the dashboard, but after the first update the dashboard values seems not to update. Any reasons? Any suggested changes to the code?

```
// Fill-in information from your Blynk Template here
#define BLYNK_TEMPLATE_ID "TMPL3CkIZFISg"
#define BLYNK_TEMPLATE_NAME "AGUA"
#define BLYNK_FIRMWARE_VERSION        "0.1.0"

#define BLYNK_PRINT Serial
//#define BLYNK_DEBUG

#define APP_DEBUG

// Uncomment your board, or configure a custom board in Settings.h
//#define USE_SPARKFUN_BLYNK_BOARD
//#define USE_NODE_MCU_BOARD
//#define USE_WITTY_CLOUD_BOARD
//#define USE_WEMOS_D1_MINI

#include "BlynkEdgent.h"
#include "DHT.h"
#define DHTPIN 4 
#define DHTTYPE DHT11

DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE);
int t, h, s;

BLYNK_WRITE(V0)
{
  if(param.asInt()==1){
    digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
  }
  else{
    digitalWrite(2, LOW);
  }
}

BLYNK_CONNECTED()
{
  Blynk.syncVirtual(V0);
  Blynk.virtualWrite(V3, s);  
  Blynk.virtualWrite(V1, h);
  Blynk.virtualWrite(V2, t);
}

void setup()
{
  pinMode(2, OUTPUT); // Initialise digital pin 2 as an output pin
  Serial.begin(115200);
  dht.begin();
  delay(2000);

  BlynkEdgent.begin();
}

void loop() {
  s= ( 100.00 - ( (analogRead(A0)/1023.00) * 100.00 ) );
  h = dht.readHumidity();
  t = dht.readTemperature(); 
  Serial.print("soil= ");
  Serial.println(s);
  Serial.println("temp= ");
  Serial.println(t);
  Serial.println("hum= ");
  Serial.println(h);
  BlynkEdgent.run();
  delay(2000);
}
```

The sensors like dht11 and soil moisture sensors are giving updated values to the nodemcu in real time. But on the blynk dashboard its not being updated at all. The value which appeded first will be struct until I restart the board.Is there any way to update the values for atleast every 2mins.

Comment: https://docs.blynk.io/en/getting-started/how-to-display-any-sensor-data-in-blynk-app#send-data-with-blynk-library-firmware-api